# Регулярный выражения, объясните строку. Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

`c = re.findall("(?s)—(.*?)[—.?]", a)`

я знаю, что оно делает, берёт все данные, которые находятся между символами — и —.? , но вот как именно работает эта строка совсем непонятно.

Comment: Думаю что вот этот сайт Вам многое поможет понять https://regex101.com/

Comment: Да даже просто [википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) можно почитать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?s)—(.*?)[—.?]
```

- `(?s)` — инлайн-модификатор/флаг, который говорит, что далее в паттерне воспринимать `.` как любой символ, включая перевод строки
- `—` — начинаем с символа тире
- `(.*?)` — 0+ любых символов (за счёт предыдущего флага) в lazy-режиме, т.е. как можно меньше
- `[—.?]` — заканчиваем одним из трёх символов: тире, точка, вопросительный знак (в таком контексте `.` воспринимается именно как точка, а не как любой символ, несмотря на флаг)

Из-за наличия флага получаем, например, матч тут:

> wombtowm **— rgr**
>
> **tgw —** wtbwrbtwtr

Из-за lazy-режима получаем, например, именно такой матч тут:

> wombtowm **— rgr**
>
> **tgw —** tgw — wtbwrbtwtr

Comment: Та за шо минус?